# How do I prevent a web form from being accessed by manually typing the aspx file name into the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, authorization, forms-authentication

I have created a Login page that is only for admins (so there is no need to check if the user is admin or not). The page does the check against a database where the username and password is stored. I am able to successfully check the name/password against the database and then transfer the user to the admin page, however, I noticed that I can still type http://localhost:xxxxx/AdminPage and it will take me there. How do I stop people from doing this? I have tried adding

```
<authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization>
```

to the web.config file, which stops all anonymous users from entering, but now I need to know how to allow users from the database to be given permission. (NOTE: this is not a normal Login to Default setup. This is directing to a page other than Default)

Comment: Use <Allow users="Admin,Me,Him,Whoelse">

Comment: <allow roles="Administrators, Supervisors" />

Answer (score 1):

You can user role based authorization described [here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs). 
If you use default ASP role system, you need to add some code to web.config:

```
<location path="your_page"  >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>            
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: You should include more detail in your answer, in case that link is ever broken.